# How do I access a docker-compose container from outside VirtualBox?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, owasp

I've got a Windows 10 laptop running VirtualBox 7.0.

Inside VirtualBox I've got Ubuntu 22.04.2 which is running the latest version of OWASP [crAPI](https://owasp.org/crAPI/) inside a docker container. I'm able to access crapi-web from the browser inside Ubuntu but I've been unable to access it from the browser on Windows.

I've spent a couple of days trying solutions I've Googled, without any success. They all involved either forwarding some ports (while the network is set to NAT) or editing the docker-compose.yml file. I've also tried accessing it via many different IP addresses as I'm unclear on which one I should be using.

I've now set the VirtualBox networking setting to 'bridged' and can successfully use Windows CMD to ping the Linux environment on 192.168.1.102

I can also successfully ping the docker-compose container (running crapi-web) from within the Linux environment on 172.19.0.9

However, when I use Windows CMD to ping 172.19.0.9 it returns nothing.

I also have the following lines in docker-compose.yml

```
crapi-web:
    container_name: crapi-web
    image: crapi/crapi-web:${VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "${LISTEN_IP:-127.0.0.1}:8888:80"
```

I've spent most of my time with the VirtualBox network set to NAT while I try forwarding various ports. But now it's set to bridged and I'm at least able to ping it I think I'm on the right track. But I'm unsure on what else I can try. Also, here's the command I'm using to start the container:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --compatibility up -d
```

EDIT: I've tried temporarily disabling Windows firewall then restarting Firefox. But still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simpl, Set virtual box networking to bridge it will share your Windows networking to virtual machine. Then you will be able to access this from your windows as well as ubuntu.

Comment: That's what I read in some other places, But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).